# Trigonometric function- Equation

Tags: trigonometry

Let $n$ be a positive integer such that

$$sin\frac{\pi}{2n}+cos\frac{\pi}{2n}=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}$$

then n lies is what interval?

Its easy to see that $$|\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}|\le \sqrt{2}$$ and hence got the value of $n$ in the interval of $[0,8]$

Now we can also see that the above LHS can be reduced to $sin(\pi/2n + \pi/4)$ and this must always be positive hence 
$$0\le\pi/2n + \pi/4\le\pi$$ which implies that $n>2/3$ hence the answer must be $[2/3,8]$

But this is wrong as the answer is $(4,8)$. Please tell me where I am wrong.

Comment: I would say the correct interval is $[6,6]$ :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only positive integer such that equality holds is $\color{red}{n=6}$.
The LHS is a decreasing function over $(0,8)$ while the RHS is in increasing function.